# How to split an Array[Double] at point n

Tags: arrays, scala, split

I have an Array[Double], and i want to split it at a specific point n.

For example:

```
val a = Array[Double](1., 2., 3., 4., 5.)
```

Suppose i want to split the array at point:

```
val n = 3
```

I want the split result to be:

```
a1 = Array[Double](1., 2., 3.)
a2 = Array[Double](4., 5.)
```

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array.splitAt(Int)` method:

```
a.splitAt(3)
```